# Duvida Socket Server

Tags: java, socket

Estou com uma dúvida no comportamento do trecho de um código que esta criando um socket server, segue o código do servidor:

```
public class Server {

public static void main(String args[]){
    try {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(3322);                       
        System.out.println("Servidor iniciado na porta 3322");

        Socket cliente = server.accept();
        System.out.println("Cliente conectado do IP "+cliente.getInetAddress().
                getHostAddress());
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(cliente.getInputStream());
        while(entrada.hasNextLine()){
            System.out.println(entrada.nextLine());
        }

        entrada.close();
        server.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Após o cliente se conectar ao server e por exemplo não digitar nada... o método entrada.hasNextLine() não deveria retornar **false** encerrando assim o **while** e fechando o **socket**? por que isso não acontece e o código fica "eternamente" esperando receber mensagens digitadas pelo cliente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porque uma operação envolvendo digitação via teclado é um input de dados infinito, ou seja, o sistema fica eternamente em estado de espera pela próxima linha a ser digitada, mesmo que ela nunca de fato o seja. Em outras palavras, esse método tem a capacidade de bloquear a execução do resto do programa enquanto espera pelo próximo input, que pode nunca acontecer se o usuário resolver não digitar mais nada. A documentação deixa isso explícito:

> public boolean hasNextLine()
>
> Returns true if there is another line in
> the input of this scanner. **This method may block while waiting for
> input**. The scanner does not advance past any input.

Você, no caso, poderia checar se a linha está vazia como condição de saída do `while`.

Comment: humm isso quer dizer que se nada tenha sido digitado pelo cliente o método hasnextline() não retorna nem **true** nem **false** , ele fica parado neste ponto aguardando algum entrada?

Comment: @MateusGuilherme Editei minha resposta adicionando informações.